# Is there an evdev equivalent in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, evdev

I want to make a program that decodes the input given by a barcode scanner, is there an equivalent to evedev for windows so I would be able to read the input
given by this device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a [HID event manager](https://pypi.org/project/hid/#data)?

```
pip install hid
```

Keyboard and barcode scanners comprise HIDs (Human Interface Devices).